# How to use devtool to fix an outdated patch

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm porting a layer to `kirkstone` which as an outdated patch which cannot be applied anymore (to `u-boot`). Can `devtool` be used to fix that patch? The problem is that per default `devtool modify` applies the patches and therefore fails to load the workspace.

Comment: The output gave hint. I'll try and update this post accordingly: 
```
The context lines in the patches can be updated with devtool:

    devtool modify u-boot
    devtool finish --force-patch-refresh u-boot <layer_path>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The patch refresh is indeed the best method if `devtool modify` can apply the patches with an offset. When `devtool modify` fails to apply the patches, one way to update the patches is:

1. Remove the patches which no longer apply from `SRC_URI`
2. Run `devtool modify` as usual
3. Port the patches manually and re-commit them
4. Terminate as usual with `devtool finish`

Of course, if a patch does not apply because it was integrated upstream, the right solution is to just remove it from `SRC_URI`.